# Maatexcel is not accpting my additional field value for import

Tags: php, laravel, maatwebsite-excel

I am trying to import excel file which is working fine. But when I try to add custom additional field values during import then those additional value is not getting import.

```
public function __construct($from, $to)
    {
        $this->from = $from;
        $this->to = $to;
    }
    
/****** Import Function *******/
public function model(array $row)
{
   
    return new pgimport([
        'field_one' => $row[0],
    'field_two' => $row[1],
    'field_three' => $row[2],
    'field_four' => $row[3],
    'field_five' => $row[4],
    'field_six' => $row[5],
    'field_seven' => $row[6],
    'field_eight' => $row[7],
    'additional_field_one' => $this->from, //Additional Value
    'additional_field_two' => $this->to, //Additional Value
    ]);
}
```

In above code, I tried to echo both addition value ($this->from and $this->to) like this

```
public function model(array $row)
{
 echo $this->from.' and '.$this->to; //ECHOING Values
    die;  //DIE TO STOP CODE

return new pgimport([
    'field_one' => $row[0],
    'field_two' => $row[1],
    'field_three' => $row[2],
    'field_four' => $row[3],
    'field_five' => $row[4],
    'field_six' => $row[5],
    'field_seven' => $row[6],
    'field_eight' => $row[7],
    'additional_field_one' => $this->from, //Additional Value
    'additional_field_two' => $this->to, //Additional Value
 ]);
}
```

In echo function, values of both variables are getting printed. So values are coming in variables but not submitting to database. Any idea please, why is this not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your model class file first. you should add 'additional_field_one' and 'additional_field_two' inside fillables. please check it firstly

Comment: Ohh crap... that actually worked. My all other column were set to fillable but not those 2. I made them fillable and it started working. Thanks ^^